# Mostrar la fecha actual cada vez que un comando se ejecute

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

¿Hay algún comando o función que muestre la fecha cuando se ejecuta un comando?

Uso SQL Developer, y por ejemplo si ejecuto:

```
select sysdate from dual
```

pone la fecha de sistema, y yo quiero que salga la fecha con horas, minutos y segundos. ¿Cómo podría hacer eso?

Comment: Le falta información a esta pregunta. ¿que motor de BD estás usando?. Lo otro, por comando, te refieres a sentencia? Ademas, te falta explicitar si quieres tener la hora dentro de tu sentencia. Aclara por favor.

Comment: Es sql developer, por ejemplo si ejecuto: select sysdate from dual pone la fecha de sistema, y yo quiero que salga la fecha con horas,minutos y segundos.

Comment: Edita la pregunta...

Answer (score 2):

Si vas a la [documentación de Oracle para `SYSDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm), se incluye un ejemplo en el que se formatea la salida de dicha función para que muestre fecha y hora con horas, minutos y segundos como quieres:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW"
     FROM DUAL;

NOW
-------------------
04-13-2001 09:45:51
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando SQL Server podrias usar la función [CONVERT() o CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Conviertes el tipo DateTime que te arroja SYSDATETIME() al tipo varchar y en la misma funcion CONVERT envias como tercer parámetro el tipo de formato que deses darle a la fecha.

Para el formato **dd/mm/yyyy** es **103**
Para el formato **hh:mm:ss** es **8** ( 24h)

Si no encuentras el formato que necesitas ya podrías jugar con otras funciones de T-SQL para dar el formato que necesites.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar , SYSDATETIME(), 103)+' '+CONVERT(varchar , SYSDATETIME(), 8) AS ActualDate;


DECLARE @FECHA_ACTUAL AS DATETIME2
SET @FECHA_ACTUAL = SYSDATETIME()
SELECT CONVERT(varchar , SYSDATETIME(), 103)+' '+LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar , @FECHA_ACTUAL, 9),17), LEN(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar , @FECHA_ACTUAL, 9),17)) - 10)+RIGHT(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar , @FECHA_ACTUAL, 9),17),2) AS ActualDate;
```